# How to use the value of a variable as key in an R-environment?

Tags: r, hashmap

In R programming language I want to use a hash table.

How do I use the value of a variable as the key for the environment?

For example:

```
map <- new.env(hash=T, parent=emptyenv())
key <- 'ddd'
map$key <- 4
print(ls(map))
>>[1] "key"
```

The output is 'key', which means I get  a mapping from the string 'key' to the value 4. What I really want this code to do is to map the string 'ddd' to the value 4.

How can I achieve this?

PS. I don't use named list because it's slow with large amount of elements as it does not use hashing to do the search.

Comment: PPS. Named lists do use hashing. But only when it makes sense to spend the time building up the hash table, when you are using vectorised subsetting with many elements.

Comment: @hadley, is there an argument to specify whether to use hash or not in named lsits ? Or it does it automatically depending on the amount of the elements ?

Comment: @hadley, how about the efficiency of named list with heuristic comparing to hashed environment ?

Comment: All depends on what you are doing.  Hard to know without an example.

Comment: @hadley, is there any link I can see to know in detail ?

Comment: @SpiritZhang: when you say 'efficiency' you presumably mean 'compute efficiency' not 'memory-efficiency'.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As it says in `?"$"`:

```
 Both ‘[[’ and ‘$’ select a single element of the list.  The main
 difference is that ‘$’ does not allow computed indices, whereas
 ‘[[’ does.  ‘x$name’ is equivalent to ‘x[["name", exact =
 FALSE]]’.  Also, the partial matching behavior of ‘[[’ can be
 controlled using the ‘exact’ argument.
```

So you want:

```
map[[key]] <- 4
> print(ls(map))
[1] "ddd" "key"
> map[[key]]
[1] 4
```