# Using Lists to form data.frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have an environment I'm using as a hashmap (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432248/how-to-use-the-value-of-a-variable-as-key-in-an-r-environment)) that's storing a count of references to that key in another document.

Now I'm hoping to draw up a bar plot of the keys vs values ordered by those with the highest value.

To me it seems that the easiest way to do the sort (while keeping shared indexes between keys and values) would be to put my data into a data frame. So step 1, i extracted the keys and values from the map to two lists as below:

```
i<-0
keys <- list()
values <- list()

for (key in ls(contactsMap)){
  keys[i]<-key
  values[i]<-contactsMap[[key]]
  i<- i + 1
} 

values.num <- as.numeric(values) # to avoid character lists.
```

But now i cant seem to be able to get them to form a simple 2 column data frame.
I'm extremely new to R and I'm sure its something simple I'm missing, but no amount of searching will shed any light on the matter.

any suggestions on how to form a data frame from two lists or, more directly, how to sort two lists while keeping the relationship between them would be amazing.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `order`, and please make your example reproducible. We don't have `contactsMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(keys, values) #and then you can sort it like this:
df[order(df$keys),]
```